# Excel - stipulate an average for random number function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to use the RANDBETWEEN function to generate a series of random numbers in Excel but also make those random numbers come out to equal a specified average. I would be using this to fill out a pricing sheet, so for example, if I use RANDBETWEEN to fill out 100 rows and I need the average to be $50 I know that I could fill out the rows by using RANDBETWEEN(25,75) and drag it through the 100 rows but it won't necessarily come out to the average price I need. Does anyone know if this is possible to amend allowing me to stipulate that average? thanks for any help

Comment: There actually is a way to have random numbers average a target, but it requires two random steps.  Start with the median = target.  In your example, RANDBETWEEN(25,75) should have a median of 50.  For a large number of values, this will be close.  Step 2: randomly assign penny adjustments to the values until you eliminate the error ("solve-for" or VBA).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a lottery in which the sponsor sells a bunch of tickets (let’s say 100),
puts them into a container (let’s call it a hat),
and then randomly selects a ticket from the hat to decide who wins a prize. 
Now suppose there are multiple prizes;
the sponsor draws the first prize winner, then the second, and then the third. 
Naturally, the winning tickets are not put back into the hat after being drawn,
because that would allow them to be selected again,
resulting in a single ticket winning more than one prize, which is against the rules. 
Therefore, all selections after the first are *constrained*. 
In a sense, the game is rigged,
so that subsequent winners can come only from the pool of non-winners,
as a mechanism of reaching the goal of not awarding multiple prizes to any single ticket.

Now suppose that there are 100 prizes – everybody wins something. 
By the time the final ticket is pulled out of the hat, there’s only one ticket there. 
The selection is constrained to the point of being pre-determined. 
And you know who the 100th winner is – it’s the sad guy who’s standing in the crowd,
waiting for his name to be called; the last remaining non-winner.

Your problem can be solved by a similar strategy:

- start with “truly” random numbers (by which I mean numbers
  statistically distributed according to a probability distribution of your choosing,
  e.g., uniform distribution over the range 25-75) and then
- constrain the later numbers (by adjusting the distribution)
  as a mechanism of reaching the goal of the stipulated average.

And the logic for constraining the probability distribution is simple:
don’t generate (and enter into the pricing sheet) any number
that makes it impossible to reach the goal.

I find it easier to think of the goal as achieving a specified *total*
rather than a particular *average*.  Of course these are logically equivalent. 
For example, suppose that you want only 4 numbers instead of 100. 
You want the average to be 50, so the total will need to be 4×50=200. 
Let’s say you generate the first two numbers,
*v<sub>1</sub>*=68 and *v<sub>2</sub>*=70. 
These add up to 138, so *v<sub>3</sub>*+*v<sub>4</sub>* must be 62. 
If *v<sub>3</sub>* is 50, then *v<sub>4</sub>* will have to be 12,
which is outside the valid range of 25-75. 
Solving 68+70+*v<sub>3</sub>*+25=200 yields *v<sub>3</sub>*=200−(68+70+25)=37,
so we constrain *v<sub>3</sub>* to lie between 25 and 37. 
Once *v<sub>3</sub>* is chosen, *v<sub>4</sub>* is determined;
it must be 62−*v<sub>3</sub>*;
i.e., 200−(*v<sub>1</sub>*+*v<sub>2</sub>*+*v<sub>3</sub>*). 
This is analogous to the situation with the 100th lottery ticket;
it must be what’s left over after the first *n*−1 choices have been made.

This sounds like a job for VBA, but I found a worksheet-formulas solution. 
In the following, I have chosen
to make the bounds of the desired probability distribution (25 and 75) parameters;
i.e., put them in individual cells (`A1` and `B1`)
rather than hard-coding them into the formulas.  And I use a few helper columns.

- Set `C1` to the desired total of the numbers. 
  You can just enter the constant value, or compute it
  as *average_number* × *number_of_numbers*, i.e., `=AVERAGE(A1, B1) * 100`.
- Set `C2` to `=C$1-SUM(G$1:G1)`.
- Set `D1` to `=100-ROW()`.
- Set `E1` to `=MAX(C1-D1*B$1, A$1)`.
- Set `F1` to `=MIN(C1-D1*A$1, B$1)`.
- Set `G1` to `=RANDBETWEEN(E1, F1)`.
- Drag `C2`, `D1`, `E1`, `F1`, and `G1` down to Row 100.

#### Discussion:

Let *n* be 100, the number of random numbers, and hence the number of rows. 
The following is the general implementation for the four-row example I gave earlier.

For each Row *i* (1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*),

- `Gi` is *v<sub>i</sub>*, the *i*-th random number.
- `Ei` and `Fi`
  are the lower and upper bounds of the range from which `Gi`
  is selected (as is obvious from the formula for `Gi`).
- `Di` counts down from *n*−1 in Row 1 to 0 in Row *n*;
  i.e., it gives the number of rows below the current one. 
  If you start in a row other than 1, adjust this formula accordingly.
- `C1` is *v<sub>1</sub>*+*v<sub>2</sub>*+…+*v<sub>n−1</sub>*+*v<sub>n</sub>*
  `Ci` = `C1` − (*v<sub>1</sub>*+*v<sub>2</sub>*+…+*v<sub>i−2</sub>*+*v<sub>i−1</sub>*),
  which equals (the goal value for) *v<sub>i</sub>*+*v<sub>i+1</sub>*+…+*v<sub>n−1</sub>*+*v<sub>n</sub>*
- `D1*A$1` → `Di` × `A1` is the minimum valid value for *v<sub>i+1</sub>*+*v<sub>i+2</sub>*+…+*v<sub>n−1</sub>*+*v<sub>n</sub>*
  So `C1-D1*A$1` (`Ci` − `Di` × `A1`) is an upper bound for *v<sub>i</sub>* for it to be possible to reach the goal total.

  Let’s revisit the four-row example. 
  If (hypothetically) *v<sub>1</sub>* were 126,
  it would be impossible to achieve the goal
  of *v<sub>1</sub>*+*v<sub>2</sub>*+*v<sub>3</sub>*+*v<sub>4</sub>*=200
  because of the constraint that *v<sub>2</sub>*, *v<sub>3</sub>*,
  and *v<sub>4</sub>* be ≥ 25. 
  But if *v<sub>1</sub>* were 125, it would be possible to achieve the goal
  with *v<sub>2</sub>* = *v<sub>3</sub>* = *v<sub>4</sub>* = 25. 
  So 125 is an upper bound for *v<sub>1</sub>*. 
  But, of course, *v<sub>1</sub>* is also required to be ≤ 75; the 125 limit is moot. 
  The *v* values must satisfy both sets of constraints
  (both the 25-75 range and the constraints required to reach the total of *n* × 50),
  so they must satisfy the tighter of the two bounds on each side (above and below).
  So `Fi` is the upper bound for *v<sub>i</sub>*.
- And `Ei` is the lower bound for *v<sub>i</sub>*.

Here’s a snapshot of what I got with *n* = 10:

[image: snapshot of sheet]

Naturally, pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> causes Excel to recalculate the sheet
and generate a new set of random numbers. 
But `G1:G10` always add up to 500; i.e., the average is 50.

---

> If *v<sub>n</sub>* is determined by *v<sub>1</sub>*, *v<sub>2</sub>*, …, *v<sub>n−2</sub>*, and *v<sub>n−1</sub>*, is it still really “random”?

This is an interesting question.

- If *n* is 1, *v<sub>1</sub>* is forced to be 50. 
  This is clearly not random. 
  But, of course, this is an edge case.
- If *n* is 2, *v<sub>1</sub>* is chosen randomly,
  then *v<sub>2</sub>* is set to 100−*v<sub>1</sub>*. 
  Clearly *v<sub>2</sub>* is not independent of *v<sub>1</sub>*. 
  But

  - P(*v<sub>2</sub>*=25) = P(*v<sub>1</sub>*=75) = 1/51.
  - P(*v<sub>2</sub>*=26) = P(*v<sub>1</sub>*=74) = 1/51.
  - ︙
  - P(*v<sub>2</sub>*=75) = P(*v<sub>1</sub>*=25) = 1/51.

  So *v<sub>2</sub>* is uniformly distributed over the range 25-75,
  the same as *v<sub>1</sub>*.
- Going back to the lottery example –
  the winner of the 100th prize is determined by the winners of the first 99. 
  But, before any tickets are taken out of the hat,
  every contestant has an equal chance of winning that 100th prize. 
  So the winner of the 100th prize is random.
- I’m having trouble doing the math for this question for *n* > 2. 
  So I did an empirical experiment. 
  I generated 100 random numbers between 25 and 75, and I recalculated 250 times,
  accumulating the results. 
  Then I charted the frequency distributions for several of the *v* values:

  [image: 1]    [image: 10]    [image: 50]

  <sup>(The images are links to full-sized versions of themselves.)</sup>

  Up through *v<sub>91</sub>*, the distributions look fairly uniform:

  [image: 90]   [image: 91]

  But, starting at *v<sub>92</sub>*, something interesting starts to happen:

  [image: 92]   [image: 93]

  Note that I had to change the scale at *v<sub>94</sub>* and beyond:

  [image: 94]    [image: 95]    [image: 96]
  [image: 97]   [image: 98]
  [image: 99]   [image: 100]

  It looks like the last few *v* values have non-uniform distributions. 
  I guess that, as *n* gets larger, it becomes more likely that the first *n*−10
  (or so) values will drift away from the desired average,
  forcing the last few values to the extreme numbers at the ends of the range,
  in order to bring the average back on track. 
  But, at least, all of the values should have symmetric distributions.

  - There’s no reason for them to be asymmetric.
  - My charts appear to be symmetric.

If you’re interested in pursuing this issue, you might want to ask it on [Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) – they eat questions like this for breakfast.

Comment: Interesting, except your basic assumption is not necessarily true.  The last value does not have to be constrained.  It is still random if the error correction is randomly assigned (2 stage process).  See my comment on the question.

Comment: @fixer1234: I didn't assume that it *had to be* constrained; I'm just offering this a ***a*** solution. Can you implement your answer in Excel without VBA?

Comment: Not easily, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is not theoretically possible to generate a random (or even pseudo-random) list with a fixed average because this requires that the later values depend on the earlier values and could even force you to go back and change some of the earlier values in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

As Catherine explained there is not such built-in function. 
After you create the random data you have to go back and change the data a little bit.
So the task can be done with VBA or other programming language.

Here is a VBA solution. All it does is:

1. user specifies the min, max for random function and how many numbers will be created
2. programm generates the random data
3. programm calculates the difference between the desired state and current state
4. if the numbers are too high, then it visits one row at a time and subtracts -1 until it's ok. if the numbers are too low then it visits one row at a time and adds +1 until it's ok.

### Option 1: Download a working solution

**WARNING:** Running macros that you download anywhere on the internet without knowing VBA can harm you PC. That's why there's the second option.

The working solution be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1mhwbknht0aloz/randGenerator.xlsm?dl=1). Was created in Excel 2013, so it should run ok on Excel 2010 and later.
After opening the file there should be two security popups by Microsoft: [popup1](http://imageshack.com/a/img904/40/JOP37p.png), [popup2](http://imageshack.com/a/img913/4103/o9Xksr.png). You have to accept them. Running is very simple: just click the button...

### Option 2: To install the macro

Open Excel -> Alt+F11 -> Insert -> Module -> paste the following code -> Ctrl+S -> and select 'Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)' from the drop-down list

```
Sub RandomGenerator()
    Dim min, max, cnt As Variant

    Do While True
        min = InputBox("Set the minimum", "Generating random with average", 25)
        If min = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(min) Then
            MsgBox "Minimum has to be an integer. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        ElseIf CInt(min) <= 0 Then
            MsgBox "Minimum has to be a positive integer. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Do While True
        max = InputBox("Set the maximum", "Generating random with average", 75)
        If max = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(max) Then
            MsgBox "Maximum has to be an integer. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        ElseIf max <= min Then
            MsgBox "Maximum has to be greater than minimum. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        ElseIf ((CInt(max) + CInt(min)) Mod 2) = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Average of (min + max) has to be even. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Do While True
        cnt = InputBox("Set the count of numbers to generate", "Generating random with average", 100)
        If cnt = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(cnt) Then
            MsgBox "Count has to be an integer. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        ElseIf CInt(cnt) <= 0 Then
            MsgBox "Count has to be a positive integer. Try again.", vbExclamation, "Wrong input"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Call generateRandomWithAverage(CInt(min), CInt(max), CInt(cnt))
End Sub

Sub generateRandomWithAverage(min As Integer, max As Integer, cnt As Integer)
    Dim random As Double
    Dim i, avg, sum, desiredAvg, diff As Integer

    sum = 0
    desiredAvg = (min + max) / 2

    For i = 1 To cnt
        Cells(i, 1) = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(min, max)
        sum = sum + Cells(i, 1)
    Next

    diff = sum - desiredAvg * cnt

    i = 1
    Do While diff <> 0
        If diff > 0 Then
            If Cells(i, 1) = min Then GoTo continue
            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) - 1
            diff = diff - 1
        Else
            If Cells(i, 1) = max Then GoTo continue
            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) + 1
            diff = diff + 1
        End If

continue:
        i = i + 1
        If i > cnt Then
            i = 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

#### To run the macro:

1. Make sure that you're in the worksheet you want to be! And click anywhere into the worksheet! (Because this macro runs in the Activated Worksheet)
2. Alt+F11 -> Click on the second row in code -> press F5

You can also create a button in the worksheet and assign the macro to it - it's more user-friendly and you don't have to check that you're in the right worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! Even though I am sure that this will work, I am not proficient enough with computers to be sure that I would do this correctly. I do appreciate your effort though