# How to simulate 25 numbers using randbetween 0,365 so that their total is 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I make it so that on Excel when I simulate 25 random integers between 0 and 365 so that their sum is 365? Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - stipulate an average for random number function](https://superuser.com/questions/865723/excel-stipulate-an-average-for-random-number-function)

Comment: You will never have two numbers >182, never 3 numbers > 121 ... Your numbers will be skewed to the smaller end and there will be at least N zeros when the highest number chosen is 341 + N. Assuming these are whole numbers.

Comment: First decide on how the odds are distributed over the numbers 0 to 365, is it strictly one in 366 (0 to 365) for the first pick and the subsequent picks are, 0 to (365 - sum of all previous picks). Ln may also be interesting. Regardless of the odds distribution mechanism and depending on the purpose, consider randomizing the 25 buckets once they are filled with the numbers totaling 365. So five buckets filled to a total of 100 may look like `60 25 5 8 2` randomize the order `25 8 60 2 5`

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three possible approaches:

1. generate unconstrained and then apply constraints
2. generate the full solution-set and pick one of these at random
3. use a *croupier*

This is an example of *croupier*.  The code will use cells **A1** through **A25**.  It:

- generates a random number between 1 and 25
- uses the result of the first step to determine which cell to increment
- increments the cell by **1**
- repeats the first three steps **365** times

Sample code:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To 365
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 25)
        With Cells(j, 1)
            .Value = .Value + 1
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: I believe with this approach the odds of picking the same cell as the first one chosen to achieve, 24 zeros and a 365, are 1 in 25^24 = 3.5527137e+33. Doesn't matter which bucket is chosen first, but the odds of picking that particular bucket again are 1 in 25 and there are 24 subsequent pics all having these odds of randomly picking the first chosen bucket. So the odds of all 24 picks being this originally picked bucket are 1 in 3,552,713,700,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Comment: @TedD.  **you are correct!**  If we pick a different method *(like cascading randbetweens)*, the probability of getting at least one 365 would increase to 1 in 365!

Comment: @TedD. This distribution of values from 0 to 365 is **not** uniform.  In fact it **can't be** uniform.

Comment: I agree. There are some comments I posted to the OP section in consideration of this. The croupier approach is as valid as the next. I just did a jaw drop when I realised what the odds would be.

Comment: oops, I mixed up the numbers chosen in the question with the number of times a bucket will be chosen using this croupier method, not 24 more times, but rather 364 additional times one of the 25 buckets gets another one. So the actual odds are much bigger/worse at 25^364 = 7.082117968407123e+508 Not enough room in one comment box to type out 508 zeros. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25%5E364

Answer (score 1):

Without giving full answer, because 1) the OP didn't provide any evidence of effort to solve, and 2) these generic types of question always makes me think this is a homework problem some teacher assigned (especially when duplicates are noted)...

Using formulas:

cell A1:`365` 'the desired ending number

cell A2: `=RANDBETWEEN(0,$A$1)` 'the first random number

cell A3 to cell A26: `=RANDBETWEEN(0,$A$1-SUM(XXXXX))` 'I'm leaving the XXXX range for you to figure out

cell A27: `=SUM(A2:A26)` 'test to see A2 to A26 adds up to 365

Comment: A very nice approach to an interesting problem.